# C - A strange Seg fault error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I can't compile this because of a segfault. Using the Tree quadrant to show max capacity gives me that error. A strange thing is that it works inside the function Quadrant, but in the insert Dot doesn't works. The create tree function is fine and the quadrant too. But when I try to access something inside the tree quadrant (the quadrant isn't NULL, I've checked before) keeps me running a segfault problem notification. I'm afraid that's a very simple error, but I can't see what it is. I've tried to search on the Internet (and found nothing) but I'm running out of time to do this full program (and I'm stuck on this for hours).
Can anyone help me, please?
Here's the code:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <float.h>
    #include <limits.h>



        typedef struct dot{
            double x;
            double y;
        }Dot;


        typedef struct quadrant{
            int max_capacity, used_capacity;
            Dot max,min;
            Dot * dots_;
        }Quadrant;


        typedef struct quad_node * Quad_node_Pointer;

        typedef struct quad_node{
            Quadrant * key;
            Quad_node_Pointer child[4];
            Quad_node_Pointer father;
        }Quad_node;


        typedef struct tree{
            Quad_node * end_;
            Quad_node * start_;
        }Tree;





        void insert_dot(Tree * A, Dot b){
            printf("lalala\n");
            Quad_node * Aux, *Aux2, * New_leafs[4];
            Dot min_aux,max_aux;
            int i;
            Aux=(Quad_node_Pointer) malloc (sizeof(Quad_node));
            Aux2=(Quad_node_Pointer) malloc (sizeof(Quad_node));
            printf("lalala\n");
            //Here's the segfault line:
            printf("this doesnt works %i",A->start_->key->max_capacity);

        void Create_quadrant (Quadrant * A, int capacity,  Dot max, Dot min){
            A=(Quadrant*)malloc(sizeof(Quadrant));
            A->dots_ = (Dot*) malloc (capacity * sizeof(Dot));
            int i;
            for (i=0;i<capacity;i++){
                A->dots_[i].x=-1;
                A->dots_[i].y=-1;
            }
            A->max_capacity=capacity;
            //But here it works perfectly. What's the diference from the other that do 
            //a segfault?
            printf("\n this works \n %i \n",A->max_capacity);
            A->used_capacity=0;
            A->max.x=max.x;
            A->max.y=max.y;
            A->min.y=min.y;
            A->min.x=min.x;
            }

    void Create_tree (Tree * A, int capacity){
        int i;
        Dot max,min;
        max.x=DBL_MAX;
        max.y=DBL_MAX;
        min.x=0;
        min.y=0;
        A->end_ = (Quad_node_Pointer) malloc (sizeof(Quad_node));
        A->start_=(Quad_node_Pointer) malloc (sizeof(Quad_node));
            for (i=0;i<4;i++){
                A->start_->child[i]=A->end_;
            }
            A->start_->father=A->end_;

        Create_quadrant(A->start_->key,capacity,max,min);
    }
```

Here's a main, just for a example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Tree * A;
    int i;
    A = (Tree*) malloc (sizeof(Tree));
    Dot b,teste[10];
    b.x=5.0;
    b.y=6.0;
    Create_tree(A,8);
    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        teste[i].x=(double)2.0*i;
        teste[i].y=(double)2.0*i;
        insert_dot(A,teste[i]);
    }
    insert_dot(A,b);
    free(A);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thanks for reading or/and helping me.

EDIT:
Just to remember, I've forgot. The insert dot function isn't full there. The focus is on the segfault problem. And the main is from the example it's running based on the full function. Sorry for any trouble. But my problem now is with this strange segfault. I think that the rest of the function is ok, and I've omitted to keep my question more simple (And isn't related to the rest of the function).

Comment: Segfaults occur at run-time, not compile-time.  Try debugging using GDB or run Valgrind.

Comment: quick look your `Create_tree(A,8)` seems low since you are iterating over 10 elements. Try `Create_tree(A,10)`

Comment: I've debugged. The error is on:
 //Here's the segfault line:
   printf("this doesnt works %i",A->start_->key->max_capacity);
But I don't know why it can't access or doesn't recognize the max_capacity from tree quadrant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go...  I'll show relevant code, ignoring irrelevant lines in between.

First, you allocate storage and initialise the tree...

```
A = (Tree*) malloc (sizeof(Tree));
Create_tree(A,8);
```

The `Create_tree` function initialises stuff on `A`:

```
    A->end_ = (Quad_node_Pointer) malloc (sizeof(Quad_node));
    A->start_=(Quad_node_Pointer) malloc (sizeof(Quad_node));
    for (i=0;i<4;i++){
        A->start_->child[i]=A->end_;
    }
    A->start_->father=A->end_;
```

Okay, so now `A->start_` and `A->end_` have uninitialised storage, except that you have set the four child pointers in `A->start_->child[]`.

At this point, you call `Create_quadrant` to initialise the `A->start_->key`, passing an uninitialised pointer.

```
    Create_quadrant(A->start_->key,capacity,max,min);
```

Here is the function declaration:

```
void Create_quadrant (Quadrant * A, int capacity,  Dot max, Dot min);
```

There is no way to get your newly initialised quadrant back out into `A->start_->key`.  You obviously want to do this because the first line of that function does this:

```
        A=(Quadrant*)malloc(sizeof(Quadrant));
```

This breaks the paradigm of your code so far, where you take responsibility for allocating data and then call a function to initialise it.  If you want the init function to give you back a pointer that is allocated inside the function, you either need to return it or pass a double pointer.

So option 1 is:

```
Quadrant * Create_quadrant (int capacity,  Dot max, Dot min)
{
    A=(Quadrant*)malloc(sizeof(Quadrant));
    //...
    return A;
}

// Called like this:
A->start_->key = Create_quadrant( capacity, max, min );
```

And option 2 is:

```
void Create_quadrant (Quadrant ** pA, int capacity,  Dot max, Dot min)
{
    A=(Quadrant*)malloc(sizeof(Quadrant));
    // ...
    *pA = A;         
}

// Called like this:
Create_quadrant( &A->start_->key, capacity, max, min );
```

I forgot to mention that option 0 is to continue with the convention you've used thus far:

```
// Called like this:
A->start_->key = (Quadrant*)malloc(sizeof(Quadrant));
Create_quadrant( A->start_->key, capacity, max, min );

// And obviously you DON'T malloc a new A inside Create_quadrant().
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly now. Sorry I can't vote up because it need 15 reputation, but when I get it I'll remember to do.
Again, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're not `malloc`ing enough space for your `Quadrant`s, because you're only giving them as much room in memory as a `Quad_node` would take up, and presumably `Quad_node`s take up less space than `Quadrant`s.